# dplyr/arrange order variable by complex conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

there is dataframe raw_data , i want to arrange value by varible `item`. Wish `total` in the first row,following are rows contains `cat_`,`sub_` and others. Below`arrange()` code failed, How to fix it? thanks!

```
library(tidyverse)

raw_data <- data.frame(item=c('cat_b','cab_a','cat_w','total','sub_1','other_1','sub_2','t_1'),
                       value=c(1,2,4,3,5,9,10,8))
#below code can't work
raw_data %>% arrange(
  match(item,
        c('total',contains('cat_'),contains('sub_'),everything())
        )
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `slice()` and `match()`, e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)

raw_data <- data.frame(item=c('cat_b','cab_a','cat_w','total','sub_1','other_1','sub_2','t_1'),
                       value=c(1,2,4,3,5,9,10,8))

raw_data %>%
  slice(match(c('total',
                grep(pattern = 'cat_',
                     x = raw_data$item,
                     value = TRUE),
                grep(pattern = 'sub_',
                     x = raw_data$item,
                     value = TRUE),
                grep('total|cat_|sub_',
                     x = raw_data$item,
                     value = TRUE,
                     invert = TRUE)),
              item))
#>      item value
#> 1   total     3
#> 2   cat_b     1
#> 3   cat_w     4
#> 4   sub_1     5
#> 5   sub_2    10
#> 6   cab_a     2
#> 7 other_1     9
#> 8     t_1     8
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You could introduce a temporary variable `sort_order` as follows:

```
raw_data %>%
  mutate(
    sort_order = ifelse(item == "total", 1,
                        ifelse(grepl("^cat_", item), 2,
                               ifelse(grepl("^sub_", item), 3, 4)))
  ) %>%
  arrange(
    sort_order, item
  )
```

Output:

```
     item value sort_order
1   total     3          1
2   cat_b     1          2
3   cat_w     4          2
4   sub_1     5          3
5   sub_2    10          3
6   cab_a     2          4
7 other_1     9          4
8     t_1     8          4
```